# how to read data from file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, file, dataframe

I want to write `vehiclelist` from a file instead of writing them here one by one. For example, I want to read 1000 `vehicleid` from the file.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import psycopg2
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
import json
import time

start_time = time.time()
while True:
    temp = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    **vehicleList = {"LTZ1246", "SN63NBK", "LX12DJY", "YX16OKV", "YX68UTM", "LX59EDK", "YY18TLX", "SO68HDX", "BL65OYK","YY67UTP", "YY18TKO", "SN16OKV", "LX59ECJ", "LX12DCY", "YY18TKO", "LX12DGE", "LX58CGE", "BF15KHB", "SN14TXR", "SN67XCB"}**
    for ids in vehicleList:
        r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Vehicle/' + ids + '/Arrivals')

        r = r.text
        temp = pd.read_json(r)
        temp['Type'] = 'ids'
        df = pd.concat([df, temp], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:3434@127.0.0.1/postgres')
    df['timing'] = list(map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), df['timing']))
    df.to_sql('tfl_bus_pg2', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What kind of file are you reading from?